# fixed size C-style arrays in class declarations

Tags: c++

I've come across a bit of code which essentially looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>

// in a header file
class xxx{
  public:
    xxx() { xxx_[0]=0; xxx_[1]=0; xxx_[2]=0;}
    double x0() const {return xxx_[0];}
  private:
    double xxx_[3];  // ???
};

// in the main.cpp
int main(){
  xxx x;
  std::cout<<x.x0()<<"\n";
}
```

The question is --- is declaring as a class member an array of fixed size is really allowed by the standard?

Comment: Just don't go hog wild putting these things everywhere in your code.

Comment: @CJohnson: When I first saw it, my first reaction was, would you please please get rid of that right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above code. It might not be the best way to write it, but there is nothing intrinsically wrong with it.

Yes, your class xxx may contain a fixed-size array as a member. It's allowed in C too.

The compiler, even when reading the header to use it, knows how big to make sizeof(xxx) as a result.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with declaring static array as a member of class:

```
class A
{
    int a[3];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed.

Design-wise, this is often not ideal, though; arrays don't have such a nice interface as `std::array` has:

```
std::array<double,3> xxx_;

for (auto it : xxx_) {...}

xxx_.size()

std::transform (xxx_.begin(), xxx_.end(), ...);
```

etc. So if you find yourself using your (static sized) array as a container most of the time, you should replace it with `std::array` (which has no spatial overhead). If you need dynamic sized arrays, look at `std::vector`, which has a small overhead (size + capacity, however, with manual allocation, you must remember the size, too, so the only overhead is capacity).

Comment: I personally would use a `vector` or a `valarray`. Just for my education: what are big pros and cons of choosing `std::array` vs `std::valarray` vs `std::vector` for statically sized contigious in memory random-access containers?

Comment: @Zhenya: from my experience: `valarray` is great for number crunching, especially the GNU implementation (uses expression templates). But it is not a container, it lacks `begin()`, `end()` and other stuff that is required by containers. Therefore, it is not usable with with algorithms like `std::transform` or range based for. It remains: The question between `array` and `vector` is solely whether the size is fixed at compile time or not. `array` does not have any spatial overhead, `vector` must remember its size and capacity. However, depending on optimizations, differences may vanish.